# Can't change language using Alt+Shift (but only when my language is set to Russian)

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

I have two languages on my Windows 8.1 computer: English and Russian.

When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while the language is set to English, everything is working as it's supposed to; however, using this shortcut when I have Russian language doesn't change it back to English.

I've tried to change the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and it's working just fine. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> is also working fine.

The problem suddenly appeared today; there weren't any Windows or driver updates.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to set a keyboard shortcut for each language with windows 8 for more [Click Here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-8-how-switch-between-keyboard-input-languages) it explain how to switch between keyboard input languages.

Comment: The thing is that I want to do the same thing as in this instruction, but it just doesn't work for me.
Thank you for replying!

Comment: Read the explanation under this header **How to Switch Between Input Languages via Keyboard Shortcuts ** [look for it here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-8-how-switch-between-keyboard-input-languages) you have to change the settings in "Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Language".

Comment: My settings are the same as in this instruction, and it's working as intended, but only when i'm switching from Eng to Rus, it doesn't work the other way, meaning that i can't switch using Alt+Shift from Rus to Eng, but Win+Space is working, and what's that i want to solve, i want Alt+Shift working all the time. I know how to assign and change shortcuts.